# What free site(s) and resources do you use to advance your ASP.NET knowledge?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, resources

What free site(s) and resources do you use to advance your ASP.NET knowledge? Other than this one, of course. I mean, we always google for answers to daily problems with work or our personal projects, but do you have any specific "one-stop shops" to where you have advanced your skills?

I guess specifically I'm looking for middle level development skills. Like more advanced AJAX, ASP.NET, standards, etc. Beginner sites are OK too, but I'm assuming most of the people on here are past that level.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bunch of blogs of the people who work at Microsoft are usually my best resources for new and interesting stuff presented in an interesting way.

Hanselman
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/

ScottGu
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx

Phil Haack
http://haacked.com/

Bertrand LeRoy
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/

Rob Conery
http://blog.wekeroad.com/

4Guys has some good stuff too.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/

Then of course...

http://www.asp.net/

Answer (score 3):

- [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
- Local ASP.NET User Groups
- Watch the Start Page in Visual Studio
- Definitely ScottGu and 4Guys as mentioned by others

Answer (score 1):

This is a great site with video and samples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/default.aspx

And of course the asp.net website!

http://www.asp.net/